# Turn a buffer API into a forward/input iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a function `void get_new_data(char** buffer, size_t* size)` that, when called repeatedly, will set `buffer` to a new chunk of data, and will set `size` to the size of the chunk. This is my only API to go over a certain stream of data.

Is it possible to reuse `std::ifstream` or some lower-level C++ standard library class so that I can use this stream of data as if it was just a forward iterator of chars, or at least input iterator? I have text-processing code that currently only accepts an iterator of chars and it will be difficult to rewrite it to directly use the buffer API.

Comment: Could you make all the calls to `get_new_data` up-front, collect the output in a `std::vector<char>`, and iterate over that?

Comment: @user2093113: please assume the full stream does not fit in RAM. In my specific case it's currently around 300 GB and growing fast.

Comment: `boost::iterator_facade` is probably a key part of the answer.  Is there such a thing as an end of the data?

Comment: @aschepler: yeah, `get_new_data` returning an empty buffer.

Comment: @aschepler: indeed I see I could implement input iterator and enough of forward iterator that I need using `boost::iterator_facade`. Thank you, could you post it as an answer?